# Parsing a large file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a large file, over 1GB and I want to parse it by two values in it and make a hash of array references.

The following is a sampling of the file:

```
ra_uuid: 592bbb0c-2c6b-11e8-8580-00e081ea0e98
cms_uuid: a4e6bffc-2c6a-11e8-a7cf-00e081ea0e8e
mpd_uuid: bf3fd34c-2c57-11e8-8bc5-00e081ea0e5c
amLeader: 0
numAssignments = 20909996
mpg=1 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
mpg=2 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=50
mpg=1 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=100
mpg=2 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
mpg=3 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=0 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=20
mpg=4 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
mpg=3 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=0 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=20
mpg=4 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
```

So I want to get all the values for the field `mrule` as a key for the hash and all the values corresponding to its `mp_demand` in a array reference.

The following is the output I desire for the above sample:

```
{
    '140' => [40,50,100,40],
    '150' => [20,40,20,40]
}
```

My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my @bigarray;
my %hash;
my $hash_ref;
my @column;
my $key;
my $value;

open(FILE, "<", "$RESULTS_FILE/$ASSIGNMENT_MESSAGE_OUTPUT") or die("Could not open $ASSIGNMENT_MESSAGE_OUTPUT to read");

while(my $data = <FILE>){
    map {s/=/ /g;} $data;
    @column = split(/\t/, $data);
    print("the column is ". Dumper(\@column));
    $key = $column[3];
    $value = $column[13];
    $hash{$key} = $value ;
}

$hash_ref = \%hash ;
push(@bigarray, $hash_ref);
print("the hash is ". Dumper($hash_ref));
print("the demand array is ". Dumper(\@bigarray));
```

It produces the following output:

```
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'ra_uuid: 592bbb0c-2c6b-11e8-8580-00e081ea0e98
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 1.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'cms_uuid: a4e6bffc-2c6a-11e8-a7cf-00e081ea0e8e
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 2.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpd_uuid: bf3fd34c-2c57-11e8-8bc5-00e081ea0e5c
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 3.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'amLeader: 0
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 4.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'numAssignments   20909996
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 5.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 1 mrule 140 reg 7989 score 10625 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 40
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 6.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 2 mrule 140 reg 7989 score 10625 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 50
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 7.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 1 mrule 140 reg 7989 score 10625 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 100
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 8.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 2 mrule 140 reg 7989 score 10625 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 40
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 9.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 3 mrule 150 reg 7989 score 0 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 20
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 10.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 4 mrule 150 reg 7989 score 10625 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 40
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 11.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 3 mrule 150 reg 7989 score 0 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 20
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 12.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          'mpg 4 mrule 150 reg 7989 score 10625 rank 0 perc 100 mp_demand 40
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 13.
the column is $VAR1 = [
          '
'
        ];
Use of uninitialized value $key in hash element at a.pl line 19, <FILE> line 14.
the hash is $VAR1 = {
          '' => undef
        };
the demand array is $VAR1 = [
          {
            '' => undef
          }
        ];
```

Comment: You dumped the contents of `@column`, but you seem to have ignored the output because it identifies the problem.

Comment: I used, 
 use strict; use warnings qw( all );
Just didn't pasted it here.

Comment: `map {s/=/ /g;} $data ;` is one of the craziest ways of doing `$data =~ s/=/ /g;` I've seen so far. Even `s/=/ /g for $data;` would've been less WTFy.

Comment: what error does it gives you ? I am able to compile it on my end. I have used some libraries (INFO) which you may not have imported. I posted the code which I actually ran only. 
I

Comment: Tip: Don't use global variables. `open(FILE, ...)` should be `open(my $FILE, ...)`.

Comment: Tip: Don't pass one path to `open` (`"$RESULTS_FILE/$ASSIGNMENT_MESSAGE_OUTPUT"`) and use a different path (`$ASSIGNMENT_MESSAGE_OUTPUT`) in the error message.

Comment: Tip: Include the reason `open` failed (`$!`) in the error message.

Comment: Tip: You use `use strict;` to force Perl to make you declare your variables (good), but then you go and declare all the variables at the top of the program (awful). The whole point of declaring variable is to limit their scope to where they are needed. Declare them where they need to be declared, not sooner.

Comment: Tip: What's the point of turning on warnings and dumping the contents of variable if you ignore both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %mp_demand_by_mrule;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /mrule/;
    my %record = split(/[=\s]+/);
    push(@{$mp_demand_by_mrule{$record{mrule}}}, $record{mp_demand});
}

print Dumper(\%mp_demand_by_mrule);

__DATA__
ra_uuid: 592bbb0c-2c6b-11e8-8580-00e081ea0e98
cms_uuid: a4e6bffc-2c6a-11e8-a7cf-00e081ea0e8e
mpd_uuid: bf3fd34c-2c57-11e8-8bc5-00e081ea0e5c
amLeader: 0
numAssignments = 20909996
mpg=1 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
mpg=2 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=50
mpg=1 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=100
mpg=2 mrule=140 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
mpg=3 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=0 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=20
mpg=4 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
mpg=3 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=0 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=20
mpg=4 mrule=150 reg=7989 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=40
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '140' => [
                     '40',
                     '50',
                     '100',
                     '40'
                   ],
          '150' => [
                     '20',
                     '40',
                     '20',
                     '40'
                   ]
        };
```